# How to display annotation processor message in Android Studio?

Tags: android, annotation-processing

I want to write a demo using Java annotation processor in Android Studio, like ButterKnife. And I want to print some informations in **process()** method to know it has exactly run. I use **System.out.println()** and **Messager.printMessage**, but I don't know how to display these informations in Android Studio like Logcat.

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> set, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
    System.out.println("BindingProcessor is running!!!");
    messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.WARNING, "BindingProcessor is running!!!");
    return false;
}
```

And add my build output window informations:

```
Executing tasks: [:25-processor:assemble, :25-processor:testClasses]

:25-annotations:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:25-processor:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:25-processor:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:25-processor:classes UP-TO-DATE
:25-processor:jar UP-TO-DATE
:25-processor:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:25-processor:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:25-processor:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:25-processor:testClasses UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
4 actionable tasks: 4 up-to-date
```

I got the messages in one project, but in the other project, I got the other problem. I checked out the build out windows, in the first correct project, the messages showed below **:compileDebugJavaWithJava** message, but in the other project, I got the information below but no process messages:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Gradle may disable incremental compilation as the following annotation processors are not incremental: lib-compiler.jar (project :lib-compiler).
Consider setting the experimental feature flag android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true in the gradle.properties file to run annotation processing in a separate task and make compilation incremental.
```

Answer (score 1):

An annoatation processor runs during the build phase, not at runtime. The logcat window in Android Studio shows the debug log of a connected device at runtime.

To view messages printed out, you need to switch to the Build window (View -> Tool windows -> Build). All messages pertaining to the build phase are sent here.

I believe that the warning you mention, is simply a warning, it shouldn't impact your annotation processor. Perhaps you haven't added the appropriate annotation, which is why you receive no output.

Comment: I follow your steps, but in the Build Output window, No messages printed out.

Comment: Use only the `messager.printMessage()` method for output, and you will have to press the Toggle View button on the left hand side of the Build window. It's usually the first or second button. This will switch the build output window from a structured output, to a raw (console-like) output.

Comment: also consider to use System.out.println()

Comment: It doesn't work for me, in my build output window, only display the gradle task running information, but not processor messages.

Comment: I added my build output window informations in my question.Thanks.

Comment: From the output that you posted, it appears that you have two gradle modules, the annotation (I'm guessing this contains the annotations) and the processor (I'm guessing this is the actual annotation processor implementation). You need to apply the annotation processor to another gradle module (one where you will use the annotations you are processing) - for example in an app module. In the build.gradle of the app module you will have to add something like: `annotationProcessor project(":processor")` to actually use the annotation processor. Then the output will be visilbe

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my question. But I got an other problem, and I have updated my question. Hope you can save my life, haha.

Comment: I finally solve this problem for I haven't use the annotation in my app module, so that  **process()** method not run. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your messages will not print on the console, but on the build section. That's because the annotation processor runs on the build process. Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use a java lib, check the configure of the path

The Annotation Processor should register in
`path-to-lib\src\main\resources\META-INF\services\javax.annotation.processing.Processor`

with the full type name, eg`cn.djzhao.compiler.AnnotationProcessor`